# Efficiently add a column with a value

Tags: sql, t-sql, smo

I am trying to add a column to a tsql table, i do this using SMO in c#. Altering the table is fine but i want to set the column to have a value. The table contains 650 million rows and the update query is taking over a day and a half to run.

Update [TempDatabase].[dbo].[table1] set RawSource = 'DTP'

This is the query I am running above.

Can anyone think of a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I heard of the "fast add column" but only for Oracle database. 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2575782100346318728
If you use SQL Server, I don't know a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it is more efficient to copy the table with the new value and re-create the table in a single command.  Also, you might want to be sure that you have minimal logging for these operations.

Probably the best solution is to use a `default` value when you create the column:

```
alter table table1 add RawSource varchar(255) not null default 'DTP';
```

If you don't want the default moving forward, you can remove it after the column is added.

Another method uses computed columns, but basically does the same thing:

```
alter table table1 add _RawSource varchar(255);

alter table1 add RawSource as (coalesce(_RawSource, 'DTP'));
```

Comment: You will need the column definition to be `NOT NULL` otherwise it won't populate existing rows with the default value

Answer (score 0):

at the time of addition of column to table only we can set a **default value** which will applies for all rows

Note:U should keep **not null** compulsory because if not all rows are applicable with nulls

```
 alter table  table_name
 add  row_source nvarchar(5) not null default(N'DTP')
```